# Is there a way I can make more than 3 apps per one firebase project visible?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

I have a Firebase project that contains many apps, all sharing the same database, users, etc..

My requirement is to use 4 apps for android each. The problem I am facing is that firebase only allows a max of 3 apps per project to be visible at a time.

So my question is, is there a work around this max app limit in firebase?

Thanks!

Refer to this image for more details [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIhJY.png)

[image]

Comment: "The problem I am facing is that firebase only allows a max of 3 apps per project to be visible at a time." I'm not aware of that limit. Can you explain a bit more what you mean there?

Comment: As shown in the attached image I currently have 4 apps in one firebase project. 3 of those are android and one is ios. If you see the image the 3 android apps are visible and the 1 ios app is invisible. If I try to make the ios one visible then one of the android one gets invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message in the screenshot is just telling you how many apps you can display on that screen **at one time**.  It's not a limit to how many apps you can have total.  If you try to create another app in this project, I'm sure it will let you do that with no problem.  You will still be able to work with all of them.

If you have further problems with the Firebase console, I suggest [contacting Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe upgrading to the Blaze plan will unlock more?

Comment: *firebaser here* There is no difference in the maximum number of apps between free and paid plans.